# bind data from list to Grid control

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am having difficulty getting the data to show in a Telerik Grid control.  I populate a list object `GraphDetail` in my ViewModel.  Then try to use `Model.GraphDetail` to bind the data to the grid in the view.  The project compiles and runs without error and the grid does show but it is empty.  If I step through the code I can see that the `GraphDetail` is being populated with data.

Here is my ViewModel:

```
namespace AESSmart.ViewModels
{
    public class ACVoltagesTelerikGraph
    {
        public long InverterID { get; set; }
        public string InverterName { get; set; }
        public double? voltage_ac_a { get; set; }
        public double? voltage_ac_b { get; set; }
        public double? voltage_ac_c { get; set; }
        public DateTime recordTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class GraphsACVoltagesViewModel
    {
        public DateTime startingDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime endingDate { get; set; }

        public string HCSeries { get; set; }
        public List<ACVoltagesTelerikGraph> GraphDetail { set; get; }

        public void setLists()
        {
            //Code to populate InverterGoups and Inverters
        }

        public void setSeries()
        {
            //Code to populate GraphDetail and HCSeries
        }
    }
}
```

My View contains the following code to display the grid:

```
@model AESSmart.ViewModels.GraphsACVoltagesViewModel

@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.GraphDetail)
    .Name("Grid")
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Server())
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.InverterID).Title("InverterID").Width(25);
        columns.Bound(o => o.InverterName).Title("InverterName").Width(100);
        columns.Bound(o => o.voltage_ac_a).Title("Phase 1 Volts").Width(75);
        columns.Bound(o => o.voltage_ac_b).Title("Phase 2 Volts").Width(75);
        columns.Bound(o => o.voltage_ac_c).Title("Phase 3 Volts").Width(75);
        columns.Bound(o => o.recordTime).Title("Record Time").Width(150);
    })
    .Groupable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Pageable(pager => pager.PageSize(3))
)
```

Here is a screenshot of the result:
[image]

As you can see from the screenshot the grid is empty.  **So, how do I properly bind the GraphDetail list I have in my ViewModel to the grid?**

Comment: Could you check for errors in browser(F12), to see if there are any javascript errors. I think you could have circular reference, or something similar.

Comment: There is not any javascript errors in the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually encountered a very similar problem.  I could not get the graph to populate based on a list.  In order to fix it I had to change the list to a collection.  Try to use the following code for your scenario:

```
public virtual ICollection<ACVoltagesTelerikGraph> GraphDetail { set; get; }
```

Also, it looks like you are building the data as part of a larger class in the ViewModel.  So, your controller is not going to be exclusively handling the creation of the model the grid is using.  So, 'server binding' probably won't work for you.  Not to mention, it looks like you are just trying to show the data to the user and not needing them to modify it at all.  So I would databind on the client side like so:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.GraphDetail)
    .Name("Grid")
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
        .Ajax()
        .OperationMode(GridOperationMode.Client)           
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing this:

`@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.GraphDetail)`

`.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Server())`

to this:

`@(Html.Telerik().Grid<ACVoltagesTelerikGraph>()`

`.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("ActionName", "ControllerName"))`

Comment: In my `setSeries` method I build and set the data for `HCSeries` and `GraphDetail`.  Since they both rely on the same data I build them a the same time.  It is quicker this way.  If I have to use an ajax call I am doing double the work.  All of the data for the graph is present in `Model.GraphDetail`.  There has to be a way to bind the graph to it.

Comment: My apologies. The DataBinding piece is only used for grabbing the data for paging, sorting, etc. You use the BindTo for the initial binding. so you'd have like '@(Html.Telerik().Grid<ACVoltagesTelerikGraph>().Name("Grid").BindTo(Model)'

Comment: I tried `@(Html.Telerik().Grid<ACVoltagesTelerikGraph>().Name("Grid").BindTo(Model.GraphDetail)` and still the same result.  It shows an empty grid.